# How to achieve consistent page print of open <dialog> across different browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

**Problem**

Browsers print [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) contents differently.

- Chrome prints only a part of dialogs content (v121.0).
- Firefox prints no content of dialog (v123.0).
- Safari prints all content of dialog (v17.2.1).

[image: Print preview in Chrome]
[image: Print preview in Firefox]
[image: Print preview in Safari]

**Reproduction**

Run following code snippet in full page mode, click on button "Show Modal" and press `CMD & P` or `CTRL & P` to start printing.

```js
const dialogElem = document.getElementById("dialog");
const showBtn = document.getElementById("show");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close");

showBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialogElem.showModal();
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialogElem.close();
});
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-size: 60px;
}

article {
  color: darkblue;
}

dialog {
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<button id="show">Show Modal</button>

<article>
  <p><b>before 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>before 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>before 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
</article>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <p><b>inside 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <button id="close">close</button>
</dialog>

<article>
  <p><b>after 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>after 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>after 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
</article>
```

**Expectation**

Print version should:

1. show content of a dialog completely.
2. show dialog content only.

On print media all elements of the top layer should be positioned adjacent and not be stacked (likewise `display: block; position: static; overlay: none;`).

**Considerations**

MDN describes that an open dialog is placed in the top layer. These styles cannot be influenced by custom CSS.

> <dialog>s are set to display: none; when hidden and display: block; when shown, as well as being removed from / added to the top layer and the accessibility tree.

quote from [MDN about Dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#animating_dialogs)

> The top layer is a specific layer that spans the entire width and height of the viewport and sits on top of all other layers displayed in a web document.

quote from [MDN about Top Layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer)

> It is important to note that overlay can only be set by the browser — author styles cannot change the overlay value of any element.

quote from [MDN about Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overlay)

I've tried to tweak the styles in Chrome. They have some effects but the content is still not completely visible.

```
dialog:-internal-dialog-in-top-layer {
  max-height: unset !important;
  position: static !important;
  height: min-content !important;
  overlay: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please provide necessary code details in the form of a [repro]. Questions must be self-containing and not solely rely one external resources.

Comment: @tacoshy Ok, I have replaced the example.

Comment: I can't make out any difference in your snippet, between Chrome (121) and Firefox (123) on Mac.

Comment: @CBroe Firefox shows no green text and Chrome only a part of the green text if dialog is open and print preview is active. Run code snippet and press full page link. Click on button "Show modal". Press CMD & P or CTRL & P to start print mode. Do not emulate print mode in Chrome Dev Tools. Then you can spot the difference.

Comment: Stackoverflow interferes with the example. May have a look at the [same example on an other page](https://codepen.io/niklaushug/live/zYbVxwG).

Comment: I have run the code direct from the filestore on my laptop/Windows10. On Chrome it prints what is seen on the screen of the dialog inner (eg. if you scroll down it'll show the last part of inner) on all 5 of the pages. On Firefox it shows all the inner on several pages, and then the rest of the after for which there is room. Edge does the same as Chrome. I find the Edge/Chrome behavior bizarre. What would like to be printed?

Comment: @AHaworth If the dialog is open I want to print only the inner content of the dialog, if necessary fragmented over several pages. If the dialog is closed I want to print everything else.

Comment: OK, so neither Chrome/Edge nor Firefox print what you want exactly so you'll have to set up what is to be printed yourself, not depending on the browser's interpretation of printing dialogs.

Comment: Safari is close to what I need (only surplus whitespace). Firefox and Chrome are insufficient in this very case. My current approach to tackle the problem is to have a second implementation of the dialog inner content, just outside of the dialog and hidden with `@media not print`. But this feels shaky because an open dialog is still assigned to the top layer and covers the rest of the page. I hope for some CSS or JS solutions to manipulate the top layer which contains an open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As different browsers treat printing dialog in different ways the only way to achieve consistency seems to be to make sure we don't try to print a dialog.

Somewhat hackily therefore you will need a second copy of the dialog which is not normally shown, but is within a div and is the only thing shown when printing.

[Note: an SO snippet doesn't work well in this circumstance so here is the code to run e.g.locally].

```
<style>
body,
button {
  font-size: 60px;
}

article {
  color: darkblue;
}

dialog, #dialogtoprint {
  color: darkgreen;
}
#dialogtoprint {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  body.dialogshowing > *:not(#dialogtoprint) {
    display: none;
  }
 body.dialogshowing #dialogtoprint {
   display: block;
   }
 }
</style>

<body>
<button id="show">Show Modal</button>

<article>
  <p><b>before 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>before 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>before 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
</article>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <p><b>inside 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <button id="close">close</button>
</dialog>

<div id="dialogtoprint">
  <p><b>inside 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>inside 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
</div>

<article>
  <p><b>after 1</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>after 2</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
  <p><b>after 3</b> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum hic possimus deleniti modi similique, nisi officia dolores nostrum ipsa iure obcaecati at aliquam aut voluptates, magni autem laudantium commodi voluptate.</p>
</article>
</body>
<script>
const dialogElem = document.getElementById("dialog");
const showBtn = document.getElementById("show");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close");

showBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.add('dialogshowing');
  dialogElem.showModal();
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.remove("dialogshowing");
  dialogElem.close();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, probably this is currently the only way to go. 

I would like to complement, that hiding top layers content is maybe feasible by `@media print {dialog, [popover], :fullscreen {display: none;}}` but hiding everything despite `#dialogtoprint` is elaborate if `#dialogtoprint` is not a direct descendant of `<body>`.

If possible I would prefer to declare CSS rulesets for #top-layer to overwrite browsers default.